# How to prevent Windows 10 from turning on a secondary display on its login screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, login

I turn off my secondary screen with

```
C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
```

But occasionally when Windows resumes from sleep and displays the logon screen, it also turns on the secondary display output. This is quite disturbing, since the secondary display is connected to a TV and it triggers its dialog asking to switch to the others source.

Is there a way to prevent that logon screen behavior?